# angularjs $window.addEventListener is not called

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement a lazyload factory in angularjs for my project which will load third party js after window onload. But window onload event is not called every time. Please suggest the reason for the same.

Here is the code snippet:

```
    app.factory('lazyLoading', ['$window', '$q', '$rootScope', 
       function($window, $q, $rootScope) {

       var appendScriptTag = function(url){
           //will create a script tag and add to DOM.
       };

       var loadScript = function(url){
           if($window.attachEvent) {
               $window.attachEvent('onload', appendScriptTag);
           } else {
               $window.addEventListener('load', appendScriptTag, false);
           }
       };
       return {loadScript:loadScript};
    }]);
```

Now if i don't call "loadScript" function from controller and directly call "appendScriptTag" then scripts loads every time, but it loads before window onload which i want to delay.

Comment: curious why you wrap this in angular in the first place?

Comment: This is because sometimes the function is executing _after_ the `window.load` event has fired. Unfortunately, there isn't a clean way to figure out whether the `window.load` has already fired. JQuery's `.ready` has been the standard solution for it for so long now that it indeed feels odd to be doing it anywhere but, IMO.

Comment: yes figured out the same reason of failure. And changed the code to use jquery now. Thanks for help.